# Group datetime64 values per week in dataframe

Tags: python, dataset, pandas

I want to plot a bar of my data grouped per week. I made the following dataframe, with nonsense data, but it should do the trick.

What I want to do is plot per week a bar chart (%)

Does anyone know how I can do this? I'm using datetime64 so can this be done easily?

I want to make one graph which contains 52x3 bars.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import random

date_expected = np.arange('2005-06', '2006-07', dtype= 'datetime64[D]')
cat = ['True','False', 'Maybe']

value = [random.choice(cat) for i in range(len(date_expected))]

data = {'Date_expected': date_expected,  'Value': value }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


print(df.head())
```

Comment: To clarify - you want a bar chart with the counts of values for each week? That is, each week is its own bar chart?

Comment: No, sorry, I think i did not clarify that part well enough. I want one graph. with 52 times 4 bars. tnx

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to do? I am not sure why you need 52 x **4** columns, since you have 3 categories in your `Value` field.

What I did is to create a new column with the number of Week in that Year, using the `dt.week`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

date_expected = np.arange('2006-01', '2006-06', dtype= 'datetime64[D]')
cat = ['True','False', 'Maybe']

value = [random.choice(cat) for i in range(len(date_expected))]

data = {'Date_expected': date_expected,  'Value': value }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df['week'] = df['Date_expected'].dt.week

df.groupby('Value').week.value_counts().unstack(0).plot.bar(figsize=(10,30))
```

Comment: Thank you that was what i wanted exactly, the 4 columns was a mistake, i ment 3

Comment: Great then. Happy to helped. If you are satisfied you can mark as best and/or upvote the answer to let other users know that this is what you needed